# How to extract the following using pandas or regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

The following is a column in pandas data frame. I want to get all the unique values like Style, Color, Flavor, Size, Scent Name...

```
Style: Lovenest - Newborn Pillow|||Color: Gray #Style and Color from this row
Style: Baby Calendula Face Cream #Style from this row
Color: Brown #Color from this row
Color: Matrix|||Item Package Quantity: 1 #Color & Item Package Quantity from this row
Color: Matrix|||Item Package Quantity: 1 #Color & Item Package Quantity from this row
Flavor: Baby Colic Babies Magic Tea|||Size: 1 Pack #Flavor & Size from this row
Scent Name: Sensitive|||Size: 100 Count (Pack of 6) #Scent Name & Size from this row
Scent Name: Sensitive|||Size: 100 Count (Pack of 6) #Scent Name & Size from this row

In [3]: df['variations'].head()
Out[3]: 
0    Style: Lovenest - Newborn Pillow|||Color: Gray
1    Style: Lovenest - Newborn Pillow|||Color: Gray
2    Style: Lovenest - Newborn Pillow|||Color: Gray
3    Style: Lovenest - Newborn Pillow|||Color: Gray
4    Flavor: Baby Colic Babies Magic Tea|||Size: 1 Pack
Name: variations, dtype: object
```

Expected output  ['Style','Color','Flavor','Size']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [25]: data = []
...: for x in df['variations']:
...:     if pd.notnull(x):
...:         d =  {x.split(':')[0]:x.split(':')[1] for x in x.split('|||')}
...:         vals = d.keys()
...:         data.extend(vals)
...:         
...: print list(set(data))
['Style', 'Material', 'Number of Items', 'Pattern', .....
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code is suppose to work:

```
df_new = df['variations'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({x.split(':')[0]:x.split(':')[1] for x in x.split('|||')}) if pd.notnull(x) else '')
```

The column names of df_new are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can using the string methods to split the values by some pattern.

Later split each string into key value pairs and take the key part.

```
In[1]: df['variations'].str.split('\|\|\|').apply(lambda items: [item.split(':')[0] for item in items])
Out[1]: 
0                     [Style, Color]
1                     [Style, Color]
2                     [Style, Color]
3                     [Style, Color]
4                     [Style, Color]
Name: item, dtype: object
```

Edit: I see that you have changed the input and expected output. If you are trying to get the set of ALL keys in the column then you can do it all in pandas without having to iterate over it row by row.

```
In[1]: keys_list = df['variations'].apply(lambda x: [y.split(': ')[0] for y in x.split('|||')]).tolist()
In[2]: list(set([key for keys in keys_list for key in keys]))
Out[2]: ['Flavor', 'Item Package Quantity', 'Size', 'Color', 'Style', 'Scent Name']
```